# Wrap Instance of Word with a Counted Class

Tags: jquery, arrays, class, find

Say i have 3 paragraphs, not necessarily paragraph tags. The word "Wonderland" shows up 5 times across these 3 paragraphs. I need a script that can wrap these instances of "WonderLand" in a span or div, give it a common class and a counted instance class. This last part is what i need help with, the rest i know how to do.

For example, the first instance would have class="Common Instance1", the last would have class="Common Instance5".

I feel like i could store each instance in an array, then use the array index value (+1 obviously) and append that to the class name, but i wanted advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I figured out how to do this unfortunately uses both the `*` selector and a second loop to add the incremental class, so there might be a more efficient way to accomplish this.  This code will wrap the word Wonderland in a span with a `wl` class and an incremented class `wl0, wl1, wl2` etc.  Since you didn't specify the type of container tags I used the `*` selector, so depending on the size of your page this might perform poorly.  You can improve this by changing the `body` in the selector to a more concise wrapper.

```
// wrap Wonderlands
$('body *:contains("Wonderland")').each(function(i,el){
    $(this).html(function(j,v){
        return v.replace(/Wonderland/ig, '<span class="wl">$&</span>');
    });
});

// add incremental class
$('span.wl').each(function(i, el){
    $(this).addClass('wl' + i);
});
```

[**See demo →**](http://jsfiddle.net/xNegs/2/)